# integral of a squared Bessel process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_t$ be a Squared Bessel Process ($BESQ$). Define $Y_t=∫_0^tX_sds$. Do we know whether $\lim_{t→∞}Y_t=∫_0^∞ X_sds$ is finite or infinite? Does it depend on $BESQ$ parameter?

Edit.
It is obvious that $\int_0^{\infty}X_s ds = \infty$ when dimension parameter $\delta > 2$, since in this case $X_t$ is transient.

Comment: could you transform your variation to Quadratic variation ?, if yes , just to check if X is s-integrable ? for instance try to check this :https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/continuous-local-martingales/

Comment: And it is asked before here , you must cite this :http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211915/156150

Answer (score 1):

Infinite, except possible in the case $dX_t = \sigma \sqrt {X_t} dW_t$.  The recurrent case is handled as or more easily that the transient.  Look at the time interval at a collection of return times, e.g. $T_n = \inf \lbrace t > T_{n-1} + 1 : X_t =  1 \rbrace$.  The integral from $T_1$ to $T_n$ is a sum of n-1 i.i.d positive r.v.'s and so is going to $\infty$.  I believe $dX_t = \sigma \sqrt {X_t} dW_t$ exists and absorbs at  0 with probability 1, which would make  your integral finite, but either of those statements could be wrong.